# display all divs if no checkbox is checked jquery

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

i'm trying to develop a filter with jquery and dynamic checkboxs and divs coming from sharePoint list, my problem is how to display all the divs if no checkboxs are checked, here's what i did :

```
 $("input:checkbox").change(function () { 
    if ($('input:checkbox').not(':checked').length == $('input:checkbox').length) { 
        $('.flowers > div').show();  
    }
});
```

flowers is the class of my container div, i want to display all the divs in flowers div if no checkbox is checked.

Thanks for your help

Comment: And if you check something, show some div again?

Answer (score 0):

You should rather search for checked checkboxes count, show the div if count is equal to 0 else hide them:

```
 if ($('input:checkbox:checked').length == 0) { 
    $('.flowers > div').show();  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replies,actionally the " $('.flowers > div').show();" is not working

Comment: @walido: would be great if you can share the fiddle with relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("input:checkbox:checked").length == 0)
{
    // your code to show all divs
}
else
{
  //code to show the div that corresponds to checked checkbox only
}
```

Comment: Please answer the whole question, not just part of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the checkboxes not to be checked, I can get you on your way with this example:

HTML:

```
<form id="form">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car 
</form>
```

JS:

```
$("#form").change(function() {
    checkMyCheckbox();
});

function checkMyCheckbox() {
    var a = $("#form").find("input:checked").length;
    if(a == 0) {
        alert("no checked boxes");
    }    
}
```

What is happening here, you take your form with checkboxes, you get the number of checked elements.
If the number is 0, you have no checked elements. Do your stuff in the if statement

Answer (score 0):

Here's my  complete method :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#vcf-theme").accordion();
$('div.flowers-wrap').find('input:checkbox').on('click', function () {
    $('.flowers > div').hide();
    $('div.flowers-wrap').find('input:checked').each(function () {
        $('.flowers > div.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
    });
});

$("input:checkbox").change(function () {
    if ($('input:checkbox').not(':checked').length == $('input:checkbox').length) {
        alert("no one is checked !");
        $('.flowers > div').show();  
    }
});
```

});

the alert message is showing but not the divs